# cloud firestore role based access example: can user create a comment?

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

While reading the cloud firestore role based access example https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access#rules, step 4, I find it not clear whether the user can create a comment or not.

According to the above link, the comment is owned by a user, here is the data model:

```
/stories/{storyid}/comments/{commentid}
{
  user: "alice",
  content: "I think this is a great story!"
}
```

And the rules:

```
match /comments/{comment} {
  allow read: if isOneOfRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/$(story)),
                              ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter', 'reader']);
  // Owners, writers, and commenters can create comments. The
  // user id in the comment document must match the requesting
  // user's id.
  //
  // Note: we have to use get() here to retrieve the story
  // document so that we can check the user's role.
  allow create: if isOneOfRoles(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/$(story)),
                                ['owner', 'writer', 'commenter'])
                && request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid;
}
```

Note the last line of the rules, to create the comment, the authenticated user (request.auth.uid) has to be the user who is the owner of the comment. However, before even create this comment, how can this user property exist? Maybe, when create the comment, do not require the last segment of the rule "&& request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid". But when update the comment, can add this rule.

Did I miss anything? Btw, do they actually test examples before using them for online reference? It is also a pity that there is no timestamp when these online documents are created. I was told nowadays things two years old can be obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.resource` variable contains the document as it will exist after this operation is completed (assuming it is allowed). So `request.resource.data.user` is the value of the `user` field that the operation is trying to write, not the value as it currently exists (that'd be `resource.data.user`, without `request.`).

Comment: You have a point!!  I still feel it is a bit misleading. Because the description on the web says " validates that the owner of the comment matches the requesting user, which prevents users from writing over each other's comments:" also the comments between the code above says "// user id in the comment document must match the requesting// user's id." so here the "user id in the comment doc" is from the request.resource and it is compared with request.auth.uid?  How can the request.auth.uid supply a different user id for comment? thx!

Comment: 1) There should be a link to leave feedback on each documentation page, so I recommend filling it out. 2) I could try to write your UID in the document, but I can never put your UID in `request.auth.uid` (as that is populated by Firebase Authentication). If this is all confusing, I recommend giving it a try in the playground - where you can reenact most scenarios you're asking about.

Comment: 1) yes, I see there is a feedback button at the bottom. But since I don't see any previous feedbacks, I hesitated to do it. Here at stackoverflow it is more transparent so I feel more comfortable to do it here. 2) I still can't wrap my mind around this, when create the comment, the request.auth.uid should be saved as the user id in the comment document, which is, the request.resource.data.user can only thus be defiined/populated. If by try in the playground you mean emulator, thx, I will try that later.

Comment: Surely I will click the upvote when I have enough reputation point. Already clicked the checkmark. Also found that this request.resource.data.authorId is well explained at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Mzb9zmnbJs&t=980s dated Aug 4, 2020, very recent. But to be honest, I still feel a little weird that some uid (myId) can have the possibility to supply a different id (theirId) for something myId created. To me, this seems a bug waiting to be exploited. Anyway, I know very little and happy to use whatever it is :)

Comment: If you find a way to exploit the bug you think there is, please post back here with the code for that.